# Gallery schema not appearing on Sanity studio

Tags: reactjs, mern, sanity

So I have a Portfolio app, I want to add a Gallery section to it for displaying images. I created the schema(gallery.js) and added it on schema.js but it is not appearing on Sanity workspace. Any ideas?

```
import createSchema from 'part:@sanity/base/schema-creator'
import project from './project';

import schemaTypes from 'all:part:@sanity/base/schema-type'

import blockContent from './blockContent'
import post from './post'
import author from './author'
import gallery from './gallery';

export default createSchema({
  // We name our schema
  name: 'default',
  types: schemaTypes.concat([
    // The following are document types should appear
    // in the studio.
    post,
    gallery, // here 
    project,
    author,
    
    // When added to this list, object types can be used as
    // { type: 'typename' } in other document schemas
    blockContent,
  ]),
})
```

Answer (score 2):

In the `gallery` schema, what is the type? It will only appear in the sidebar of the Studio if it is a document. Anything else (including objects) will not appear in the sidebar and need to be used inside documents or other objects.